# ModuleNotFoundError when using attr with the src layout

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, setup.py

I am developing a Python package using `setuptools`. I set the configuration using a [`setup.cfg` file](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files), using the src layout. On Python 3.6 on Travis-CI, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

The src layout gives the following structure:

```
my-package
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
└── src
    └── my_package
        ├── my_file.py
        └── version.py
```

As explained on the documentation, I fetch the version using the `attr:` specifier. I also use the `extras_require` key to get some extra dependencies ([especially for having test tool executables](https://reinout.vanrees.org/weblog/2009/12/17/managing-dependencies.html)).

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = attr: my_package.version.__version__

[options]
package_dir =
        =src
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where = src

[options.extras_require]
test =
        dummy
```

Then, I use `pip` to install dependencies:

```sh
pip install -e ".[test]"
```

This works seamlessly in local environment using Python 3.7 and in Travis-CI environment using Python 3.5. But on Travis-CI environment using Python 3.6 I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
Obtaining file:///home/travis/build/me/my-package
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/travis/build/me/my-package/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        setup()
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 129, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/opt/python/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 121, in setup
        dist.parse_config_files()
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 436, in parse_config_files
        ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 106, in parse_configuration
        meta.parse()
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 382, in parse
        section_parser_method(section_options)
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 355, in parse_section
        self[name] = value
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 173, in __setitem__
        value = parser(value)
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 428, in _parse_version
        version = self._parse_attr(value)
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/config.py", line 305, in _parse_attr
        module = import_module(module_name)
      File "/home/travis/virtualenv/python3.6.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `setuptools` package provided by Travis-CI for Python 3.6 is too old to use the `attr:` specifier correctly. This feature can be used [in v39.2.0](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#metadata), whereas Travis-CI Python 3.6 provides v38.2.4 (hence the error), and Travis-CI Python 3.5 provides 40.0.0 (hence the success).

So, I just put:

```sh
pip install --upgrade "setuptools>=40.0"
```

as a prerequisite in my `.travis-ci.yaml` file.

Comment: Thanks! Just fix the same issue for GitHub Actions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when using setuptools 46.x, but my setup.cfg was slightly different. This part is important:

```
[options]
package_dir =
        =src
packages = find:

[options.packages.find]
where = src
```